# Why is a for loop faster than Array.prototype.map()

Tags: javascript

From what I've read here and tested personally using `console.time()`, a regular `for` loop in JavaScript is faster than using `Array.prototype.map()`. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because function calls are expensive.

Comment: Example code? jsPerf?

Comment: Because initializing a new scope is more expensive than not initializing a new scope? Consider `function foo() { console.log('foo'); }; foo();` and `console.log('foo');`. Which one do you think requires the interpreter to do "less work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your simple for loop looks like this:

```
var num = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  num.push(i);
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  result.push(Math.sqrt(num[i]));
```

That's pretty straight-forward and simplistic. Now let's look at a conforming EMCA-262 [implementation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map):

<sup>Taken from spidermonkey</sup>

```
/* ES5 15.4.4.19. */
function ArrayMap(callbackfn/*, thisArg*/) {
    /* Step 1. */
    var O = ToObject(this);

    /* Step 2-3. */
    var len = TO_UINT32(O.length);

    /* Step 4. */
    if (arguments.length === 0)
        ThrowError(JSMSG_MISSING_FUN_ARG, 0, 'Array.prototype.map');
    if (!IsCallable(callbackfn))
        ThrowError(JSMSG_NOT_FUNCTION, DecompileArg(0, callbackfn));

    /* Step 5. */
    var T = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void 0;

    /* Step 6. */
    var A = NewDenseArray(len);

    /* Step 7-8. */
    /* Step a (implicit), and d. */
    for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        /* Step b */
        if (k in O) {
            /* Step c.i-iii. */
            var mappedValue = callFunction(callbackfn, T, O[k], k, O);
            // UnsafePutElements doesn't invoke setters, so we can use it here.
            UnsafePutElements(A, k, mappedValue);
        }
    }

    /* Step 9. */
    return A;
}
```

Can you see why `map` is slower?

Comment: great answer, for the future I will look for the implementation of functions directly.